# Partitioning or not a table on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I know that there is not a "good" answer to my question, and it is opinion based. But since I am now learning those things on my own, I need advice.

I have a table on Mysql about "Customer". In this table there are columns referred to customer's info like name, surname, date of birth, address, and so on.

Each customer has his own credentials (username, password).

Now my question is: *It is better to keep credentials in "customer" table, or it has sense to create a separate table, in order to guarantee the protection of these credentials, and also keep track of the changes of them along time, without wasting space repeating all the others customers' info?*

Answer (score 1):

You need to answer some questions about your data:

- Do the columns change?  People change names, addresses, and so on.
- The credentials will change, at least the password.
- What sort of history do you need?

My recommendation would be different sets of tables for different purposes:

1. One table that defines the customer id and whatever other immutable information there is (perhaps the date of becoming a customer and related information).
2. One or more tables with PII (personally identifiable information).  You want to keep PII separate for regulatory and privacy reasons.
3. Tables for history.  How you do this depends on your data model and what you need.  A simple method is a single archive table per table in your data model.  However, I might recommend type-2 tables (i.e. those having version effective and end dates).
4. Separate tables for credentials.  These are even more sensitive than PII and you will want to control access.

Remember to never store clear-text passwords.  And often you want to keep a history of passwords to prevent users from using the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create personal information in the person table and additional customer information in another table that has a relationship with the customer, and if you have any other information about the person in another table and link it to the table of persons.